# PendingIntent.getService() calling IntentService onHandleIntent before Alarm scheduled time

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent, android-intentservice

The `PendingIntent.getService()` execute the IntentService `onHandleIntent()` before the time specified.

This are the code.

```
class MakeAlarm {

public static void scheduleAlarm(Context context) {

    AlarmManager manager = ....;

    boolean enabled = // Some determination logic ;

    //Intent to trigger
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ReminderService.class);

    PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent
            .getService(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    if (enabled) {
        //Gather the time preference
        Calendar startTime = // Calendar instance with time set

        //Start at the preferred time
        //If that time has passed today, set for tomorrow
        if (Calendar.getInstance().after(startTime)) {
            startTime.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Scheduling reminder alarm");
        manager.setInexactRepeating(
                AlarmManager.RTC,
                startTime.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                operation
        );
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Disabling reminder alarm");
        manager.cancel(operation);
    }
  }
}
```

This is the IntentService that is being called:

```
public class ReminderService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = ReminderService.class.getSimpleName();

    public ReminderService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "reminder event triggered");

        //Present a notification to the user
        NotificationManager manager =
            (NotificationManager) 
getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification note = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.notification_title))
                ...
                .build();

        manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, note);
    }
}
```

The Alarm Scheduling is working perfect but am getting notification instantly when I schedule an alarm. From the Log it shows the IntentService onHandleIntent is fired instantly.

Comment: sounds like your startTime is in the past. Make sure it is correct

Comment: My startTime is always in the future.

Comment: How do you know your start time is correct? Give us some examples. Logging?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set time to (today's date + 1) . Try this.

```
startTime.set(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR),
              Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH),
              Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DATE));

startTime.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
```

Comment: Am actually using `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: SimpleDateFormat is just for formatting date display, you must be working on some Date object??